# Connect neo4j server from remote machine using JAVA

Tags: neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

I have two sysytem.....System A and B..Neo4j server is installed in system B.I am running java code from system A. And my code looks like below..How to set so that data will move to remote server.

```
     GraphDatabaseFactory dbFactory = new GraphDatabaseFactory();
    GraphDatabaseService graphDb=dbFactory.newEmbeddedDatabase(prop.getProperty("/root/Sprint2/neo4j/neo4j-community-2.1.7/telcooss_demo/telcooss
"));
         ExecutionEngine execEngine = new ExecutionEngine(graphDb);
```

IS there any way I can specify the IP of the remote machine?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access Neo4j remotely, you can do so for instance using the JDBC driver, or a thin http client library.

see http://neo4j.com/developer/java

There will be more options soon.